# How to use symbolic links on shared NFS drives?

Tags: linux, symlink, nfs, shared-folders

I have two machines on the same network, and both of them have mounted the same external NFS file system (an efs from AWS), at the mount point `/mnt/efs/fs1`.

I want to do a symbolic link from both machines, using the same name of the link on both of them but pointing to different places, although one of them (the NFS volume) is common from there. I cannot do it because the NFS target, common to both of them, does not allow me to do it correctly.

On Machine A, production, I have the path `/opt/IBM/SharedArea/files/upload`, and from there, I did a symbolic link to `/mnt/efs/fs1` using the command

```
ln -s /mnt/efs/fs1/file-exports/files/ /opt/IBM/SharedArea/files/upload/files
```

If I now do a `ls` on that Machine A, I see the symbolic link correctly created:

MACHINE A:

```
[root@connections ~]# cd /opt/IBM/SharedArea/files/upload
[root@connections upload]# ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Dec 13 16:44 files -> /mnt/efs/fs1/file-exports/files/
```

MACHINE B:

Now, on Machine B, pre-production, I have the same path, `opt/IBM/SharedArea/files/upload`. This time I want to do a symbolic link to another path, `/connectionsdata`, and I did the following command for that:

```
ln -s /connectionsdata/ /opt/IBM/SharedArea/files/upload/files
```

The symbolic link is also created on this machine. I have now on Machine B:

```
[root@connections ~]# cd /opt/IBM/SharedArea/files/upload
[root@connections upload]# ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Dec 13 16:44 files -> /connectionsdata/
```

My surprise is that on Machine A, I observed that the symbolic link I did initially has changed and is also pointing to `/connectionsdata`.  It is the same on both machines. Both are pointing to the same directory (`/connectionsdata`) instead having the initially defined.

I unlinked the paths, repeated the operation several times, and it behaved similarly. The last symbolic link created overwrites the first one, which is on a different machine. I can not find any sense in this. Any hint of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make more clear what filesystems and mount points are involved with all the directory paths on both machines and where the NFS file system is mounted on both machines.

Comment: You assume that the same symbolic link (which resides on a shared drive, right?) should point to separate locations depending on what machine mounts the directory. Is that a correct assessment?

Comment: @Kusalananda, Not sure if undersood you correctly.  The only shared drive between both machines is the NFS volume /mnt/efs/fs1.....    The source of the simbolic link is on drives that are not common, but have the same path structure (/opt/IBM/SharedArea/files/upload),  the target should be different on each one the disk.   Note that disk /connectionsdata on machine B was previosly mounted on machine A, but that was previously, actually is only mounted on B.

Comment: @AndresG Are you sure there is nothing else shared between the two machines? What is `/opt/IBM/SharedArea/`? Why is it named `SharedArea`? I suggest to show the output of `mount` on both machines.